# Disable Ajax Add to Cart on the Product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, ajax

how to disable Ajax ‘Add to Cart’ button on the Magento 2 product page

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below:

**From:**

```
 {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                    "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
                }
            }
        }
```

**To:**

```
{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
            "bindSubmit": true,
            "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Open this file **`addtocart.phtml`** file available on below location.
**`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml`** and override your theme or custom module.

Step-2: Now look for the below code available around line no-42 inside file.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And replace that code with given code.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#product_addtocart_form": {
        "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
            "bindSubmit": true,
            "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And than run below commands :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And check output:-

[image]

**`THANKS.`**